# Contadores con números aleatorios

Tags: java

Buenas tardes, me dejaron hacer un código en el cual se den números aleatorios, pero el usuario de cuantos nuúmeros seran y que tambien se cuente cuantas veces se repite cada uno, van del 1 al 10, pero me sale error en el contador, este es mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner linea = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, digito, digito1, repetir;
    System.out.print("Introduce un número entero: ");
    n = linea.nextInt();
    repetir = 0;
    digito1 = 0;
    do {
        digito = n % 10;
        if (digito > digito1) {

            digito1 = digito;
            repetir = 1;
        } else {

            if (digito == digito1) {
                repetir++;
            }
        }
        n = n / 10;

    } while (n != 0);

    System.out.println("El numero " + digito1 + " se repite " + repetir + " veces");
}
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con la descripción de los errores que tengas y una explicación mas clara de qué estás haciendo. También mira [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Podrías poner qué error te da, ayudaría mucho a la hora de encontrar la solución.

Answer (score 1):

No  veo donde generas tus números aleatorios, ni comprendo por que evalúas si son múltiplos de 10, tampoco veo la necesidad de iterar n/10.

Según lo que describes que quieres que haga tu programa seria algo asi

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class RandomGenerator{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner linea = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, digito;
    int[] digits= new int [11];
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      digits[i]=0;
    }
    System.out.print("Introduce un número entero: ");
    n = linea.nextInt();

    do {
        digito = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10+ 1);
        digits[digito]++;
        n = n-1;
    } while (n != 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("El numero " + i + " se repite " + digits[i] + " veces");
    }

}
}
```

me da un resultado como el siguiente:

> ```
> Introduce un número entero: 44
> El numero 0 se repite 0 veces
> El numero 1 se repite 4 veces
> El numero 2 se repite 3 veces
> El numero 3 se repite 2 veces
> El numero 4 se repite 3 veces
> El numero 5 se repite 3 veces
> El numero 6 se repite 5 veces
> El numero 7 se repite 6 veces
> El numero 8 se repite 9 veces
> El numero 9 se repite 3 veces
> El numero 10 se repite 6 veces
> ```